# Samba shares not visible on network

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, samba

I am trying to set up a couple Samba shares and they are not visible from my Windows clients. I am able to ping the server from the clients and vice-versa, and I'm accessing the server through SSH and the print server I have set up with CUPS is still working just fine, so I know that the server is still online.

I'll get the version numbers and hardware out of the way here; I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian 9.6 Stretch headless, I have a 2tb USB drive that I'm using as the storage media, and I'm running Samba version 4.5.12-Debian, the firewall has been disabled.

I should also take a moment to mention that all of these issues have started after I shut down the Raspberry Pi and transferred it to a case.

As for the clients, they are all running Windows 10 1607 in either the Personal edition or LTSB edition flavors.

My Samba config file is below;

```
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# Written for Bistack on Raspberry Pi



#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
## Core Networking Options ##
    netbios name        = Bistack
    workgroup           = Cadosphere
    encrypt passwords   = yes
    min protocol        = smb2

## Domain Control Settings ##
    domain master       = yes
    local master        = yes
    preferred master    = yes
    security            = user

## Netbios Name Service Settings ##
    wins support        = yes
    dns proxy       = no

## Debugging/Accounting ##
    log file        = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    log level       = 1
    max log size        = 1000
    panic action        = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

## Authentication ##
    server role     = standalone server
    passdb backend      = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions   = yes
    unix password sync  = no
    passwd program      = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat     = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest        = bad user
    ntlm auth       = true  



#======================= Share Definitions =======================
## Core Samba shares and networked devices ##
[homes]
    comment     = Home Directories  
    browseable  = no
    read only   = yes
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask  = 0700
    valid users = %S

[profiles]
    comment     = Users profiles
    path        = /home/samba/profiles
    guest ok    = no
    browseable  = no
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask  = 0700

[printers]
    comment     = All Printers
    browseable  = no
    path        = /var/spool/samba
    printable   = yes
    guest ok    = no
    read only   = yes
    create mask = 0700

[print$]
    comment     = Pointer for Windows clients to find the proper Printer Drivers
    path        = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable  = yes
    read only   = yes
    guest ok    = no

## Multi-User General Shares ##
[cadosphere]
    comment     = Network folder for Cadosphere projects
    path        = /~/nas/cadosphere
    valid users = matt
    admin users = cadosphere
    read only   = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes

[shared]
    comment     = Network folder for anyone on the network
    path        = /~/nas/shared
    gues        = okay
    read ony    = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes

## Single-User Dedicated Shares ##
[matt]
    comment     = Matts network share
    path        = /~/nas/matt
    valid users = matt
    force user  = matt
    read only   = no
    browseable  = yes
    public      = yes
    writeable   = yes
```

Checking the logs from `smbd` there is nothing out of the ordinary, or any errors. But the log from `nmbd` I get this error everytime I try to start/restart `nmbd`;

```
[2019/01/28 10:37:53.650901, 0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_browsesync.c:354 (find_domain_master_name_query_fail) 
    find_domain_master_name_query_fail:
    Unable to find the Domain Master Browser name CADOSPHERE<lb> for the workgroup CADOSPHERE.
    Unable to sync browse lists in this workgroup.
```

So far I have tried to solve it with [this post on Linux Questions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/unable-to-find-the-domain-master-browser-error-in-samba-355416/), [this post on the Ubuntu fourms](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661085), [and this post on the Samba mailing list](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2013-September/175570.html), along with other various links around the internet.

Edit #1: So if I create a shortcut on the desktop to the server, I can access the shares but you can access any of them without any passwords. Also, I can't map the shares to a drive on the system and can't access the server through the file explorer, only the shortcut on the desktop.